# how to changed logo image of a Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, branding, onet

I currently try to set logo image in the Site of SharePoint Provisioning a WebTemplate.

I want to know if is exists a way to change logo without using code and by using some feature of Onet.xml

Comment: You mean to create a feature to change the site Logo?

Comment: Yes! :-) helpme

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the site logo on feature activated you need to add an event receiver to the feature.

Here is a sample code to update logo on feature activated.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb web = (SPWeb) properties.Feature.Parent;      
    web.SiteLogoUrl = "" ; //set your path
}
```